# Nginx load balancing does not work test aws servers

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have tree amazon EC2 instances:

And I have installed Apache2 in two instances

And nginx in one instance.

I have configured my nginx like:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-83-82:/etc/nginx$ cat nginx.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
     upstream lbmysite {
        server ec2-34-238-244-237.compute-1.amazonaws.com;
        server ec2-54-144-235-129.compute-1.amazonaws.com;
     }

    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://lbmysite;
        }
    }
}

$ sudo service nginx restart
```

But When I execute:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-83-82:/etc/nginx$ curl http://lbmysite
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: lbmysite
```

AndIf I do

```
curl ec2-34-238-244-237.compute-1.amazonaws.com

 _            _
| |_ ___  ___| |_
| __/ _ \/ __| __|
| ||  __/\__ \ |_
 \__\___||___/\__|
```

And In all tutorial, the people has the same instructions.

Or configuring in: /etc/nginx/conf.d

But it not works to me, I copied the same nginx.conf to that path

```
cp nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

sudo service nginx restart
```

What is my problem? :(

Comment: does `sudo nginx -t` show anything. Cause it looks like you will have `http` directive inside of `http` directive.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-83-82:~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: I don't understand why, but it works with: curl localhost:80

Comment: `lbmysite` is more or less a variable that `nginx` understands and wouldn't work outside of `nginx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring `lbmysite` as an upstream does not affect DNS resolving, so you should be able to ping successfully if you use the server IP.

Maybe you have missed a `listen` directive inside you `server` block, which could mean you NGINX is not listening to any port. Try adding some like this:

```
server {
  # Other stuff
  listen 80;
}
```

This way NGINX will listen to default HTTP 80 port.

Comment: I don't understand why, but it works with: curl localhost:80

Comment: Because http://lbmysite doesn't exists. You need to curl your IP or a resolved name pointing into your IP. That's what I meant with `an upstream does not affect DNS resolving`